# Does google maps API support real time navigation

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing a MobilePhone APP which could simplified as:

1. Dynamically add some map Markers (POI) based on client's location.
2. Client can click one of the POI to start a navigation
3. During the way to the POI, the Markers could **changes**, like colors or sth.

   Adding/changing the markers is quite simple for current API, but regarding the navigation, I searched a lot and even didn't have a firm answer if it supported, anyone help to give some hint?

Comment: no it does not support that

Comment: @tyczj so how about the 'Google Maps API for Business'? I have to say I read the (http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html) but didn't get any useful information.                so it there any work around to archive my goals?

Comment: Google Maps for business only gives you a greater limit on the number of requests and such for the API's. I made a library that uses `Googles Directions API` that will plot the route path but in googles  `TOS` it says it should not be used for real time navigation https://github.com/tyczj/MapNavigator